# PHP Object could not be converted to int

Tags: php, php-5.5, object-to-string

I just upgraded from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.5 and I'm facing a warning that I didn't get before when casting an Object to a int using the __toString() method.

The sample code is

```
<?php

class MyObject {
    protected $_id;
    public function setId($id) { $this->_id = $id; }
    public function __toString() { return (string)$this->_id; }
}

$e = new MyObject();
$e->setId("50");
if($e == "50") echo "50 == 50 as String\n";
else echo "50 !== 50 as String\n";

$e->setId(50);
if($e == 50) echo "50 == 50 as Integer\n";
else echo "50 !== 50 as Integer\n";

$e->setId("50");
if($e == 50) echo "50 == 50 as String = Integer\n";
else echo "50 !== 50 as String = Integer\n";

$e->setId(50);
if($e == "50") echo "50 == 50 as Integer = String\n";
else echo "50 !== 50 as Integer = String\n";
```

The output in my server is

```
50 == 50 as String
50 !== 50 as Integer
50 !== 50 as String = Integer
50 == 50 as Integer = String
```

While I was expecting all of them to be true. The notices I get while running it are:

```
Object of class MyObject could not be converted to int
```

They are triggered by the lines that contain the code

```
($e == 50)
```

It's this intended? Is there any variable I can set in the PHP ini to make it work differently?
Do I just need to learn to deal with it and review all my code that may use Objects as Integers in some codes?

Comment: From php docs **The __toString() method allows a class to decide how it will react when it is treated like a string. For example, what echo $obj; will print. This method must return a string, as otherwise a fatal E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR level error is emitted.**

Comment: What line number is causing the PHP Notice?

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this? Why not just write a `getId()` and compare it like `$e->getId() === 50`?

Comment: I updated the question a bit, adding the (string) removed the fatal error. However the other weird behaviour still remains.
The lines that trigger the exceptions are the code: "($e == 50)"
It's not that I want to use it like that, it's that it's already used like that and the update broke it and now I'm trying to figure out a workaround.

Comment: You wrote some code that relies on abusing some ill-defined typing and conversion shenanigans in PHP, we've all done it at some point. PHP devs have *fixed* that and broken your code. The solution is to fix your code and learn a lesson about abusing PHP's loose typing system, and @bali182 has already given you the direction for the fix.

Comment: This is because PHP is not calling __toString() magic function when you try to compare it to an int and it should not (5.3 maybe had a bug that call __toString when comparing to non strings ). I know that you wish if there was a magic method __toInt(). So you are left with changing your code to get and $_id  or downgrade and exploit a bug.

Comment: I wish I could tag Sammitch's comment as the answer.
We are reviewing our code now changing this syntaxes. Hopefully it seems that's it isn't much of a change in our code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my question by quoting Sammitch's comment

> You wrote some code that relies on abusing some ill-defined typing and conversion shenanigans in PHP, we've all done it at some point. PHP devs have fixed that and broken your code. The solution is to fix your code and learn a lesson about abusing PHP's loose typing system.

The fix was to review our code and change the code lines to either

```
if("$e" == 50)
```

or

```
if($e->getId() == 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this better would be @bali182's solution by defining another method or you can cast object to string while comparing:

```
if((string)$e == something)
```

Either way, you'll have to change your code...
*Tested on php 5.4.27

Answer (score 0):

There is no `valueOf` in PHP like we have in better languages and the interpreter is not good enough to try to convert to string and after that to other primitives. Maybe older versions supported that feature as you claim, I don't know. What you can do is `(int) (string) $myObject` or `$myObject->toInt()`. By comparison it is enough to covert to string, PHP will finish the rest if we are talking about loose equality.